# Parent tell child, that child is allowed to download image

Tags: image, asynchronous, dynamic, swiftui, scrollview

That's aproximately what my code looks like. So that you have an idea what I'm doing. In Parent view I have another list of TV Channels which user can click on and select. After that user can do a DragUp gesture and ListOfChildren is displayed. Each child holds an image, which is dynamically loaded from web. Every TV Channel has about 10 children and it has to download and display that image. That's why I want to only allow image to be downloaded and displayed when user does a DragUp gesture to show ListOfChildren.

How can I notify child from Parent, that it can start downloading image?

```
struct Child : View {
    @State var imageURL: URL 
    @State var isAllowedToDownloadImage: bool

    var body : some View {
        // if(isAllowedToDownloadImage) { <- I want to notify child from parent, that
        //                                   child is allowed to download and display image
            URLImage(url: imageURL) 
        //}
    }
}

struct ListOfChildren : View {
    @State var children: [Child] = [Child]()
    var body : some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(children) { child in 
                    Child(imageURL: child.image)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Parent : View {
    var body : some View {
        ListOfChildren 
        // with drag gesture I show ListOfChildren and after it's shown
        // I want to notify child that's it's allowed to download and display image
        // DragGesture()...
    }
}
```

Comment: You can share and `ObservableObject` between them, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: Thanks! I added a solution with your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A step in right direction was by @lorem ipsum. It works fine now, thanks!

```
struct Parent : View {
    // when I change selected channel, i set appState.startDownloadingImages to false
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

    var body : some View {
        ListOfChildren 
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                .onEnded { _ in
                    // only change state if images hasn't started loading 
                    if(self.appState.startDownloadingImages == false ) {
                        self.appState.startDownloadingImages = true
                    } 
                })
        .environmentObject(self.appState)
    }
}

struct ListOfChildren : View {
    @State var children: [Child] = [Child]()
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

    var body : some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(children) { child in 
                    Child(imageURL: child.image, allowImageDownload: self.$appState.startDownloadingImages)
                }
            }
        }.environmentObject(self.appState)

    }
}

struct Child : View {
    @State var imageURL: URL 
    @Binding var allowImageDownload: bool

    var body : some View {

        // if imageURL is empty or if images are not yet allowed
        // to be downloaded, just show empty view
        if(self.imageURL == "" || !allowImageDownload) {
            VStack{}
        }
        else {
            URLImage(url: URL(string: self.imageURL!)!,
                content: { image in
                    image   
                }
            )        
        }
    }
}
```